# Showing app name in app chooser dialog

Tags: android

My app (e.g, named "Awesome app")  intercepts a http link (say, it's a link to a Googlemap location). The link is handled in one activity named "View Activity", and it's not the main launcher. When a user clicks on that link in their email, my app appears together with Googlemap in the app-chooser dialog. However, it appears as "View Activity" instead of "Awesome app".

I don't want to change the `android:label` property of the activity to "Awesome app" since it shouldn't be named that way.
So, how do I show the app name in that case? Thanks.

**Edit:** 
I tried adding `<activity-alias>` as suggested by zmarties, like below, however, my app is no longer listed in the app chooser dialog, any idea? Tks.

```
<activity-alias android:name=".Blahblah"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/config_app_name"

        android:targetActivity="com.mypackage.activity.ViewingActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="thehost.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="thehost.com"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change what text gets shown by changing the label.  The fact that you don't want to change the label does not change the fact that that's the right way to do it.

If your problem is that as well as intercepting a link, that same activity has other uses for which you need to show a different label, then you need to split all those uses out into their own activities, so that they can each have their own specific label.  Those separate activities can all in fact be the same activity - see [activity-alias](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html)

Comment: just updated my question, `<activity-alias>` didn't work for me. You have any idea?

Comment: You've marked your alias as not exported, which will mean the chooser will ignore it.